# App is crashing while switching activitys, build is complete, no error

Tags: java, android

My app is crashing while switching from the after login activity to the in app´s profile activity.
Build is complete without errors.

Any ideas why? (Thankful for every Help)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ProfileActivity ---->

```
package com.smarthelp.smarthelp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Button logout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Logout();
            }
        });

        configureibtnHelp();

    }


    private void Logout(){
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

    }
    private void configureibtnHelp() {
        ImageButton ibtnHelp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnHelp);
        ibtnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.logoutMenu:{
                Logout();

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
HelpActivity ---->

```
package com.smarthelp.smarthelp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);


        configureibtnProfile();
    }

    private void configureibtnProfile(){
        ImageButton ibtnProfile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnProfile);
        ibtnProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HelpActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
activity_help.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HelpActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnProfile"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="ProfilButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profil" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnOrder"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="OrderButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/order" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnHelp"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="236dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="HelpButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.875"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/help" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
------->Logcat

```
08-13 19:13:15.273 21068-21068/com.smarthelp.smarthelp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smarthelp.smarthelp, PID: 21068
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smarthelp.smarthelp/com.smarthelp.smarthelp.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.smarthelp.smarthelp.ProfileActivity.configureibtnHelp(ProfileActivity.java:48)
        at com.smarthelp.smarthelp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
```

Comment: Initialized your view(`button`) in `onCreate` function .

Comment: Sorry, but do you even read your stacktraces? It clearly said NPE before, it clearly says NPE now in the updated output. The fields/variables you're trying to add click listeners to are null. Also I'd strongly suggest you to familiarize with debugging.

Answer (score 2):

From the crash log it seems

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

there is an NPE on the button for which you are trying to set onclick listener.
In your ProfileActivity set the button to one of the ImageButtons of XML
Assuming you are trying to do for first of your image buttons

just add the following line before setting onClickListener

```
logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ibtnProfile);
```

Comment: thank you for helping out, but it didnt fixed the bug

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
firebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

to

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

at line 14 in ProfileActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much said in the stacktrace: trying to call `addOnClickListener` on a null object at `ProfileActivity` on line 27

You haven't initialized `logout` button with any value. Probably forgot to `findViewById` it.